# Comparing floating point / decimal values from Informix to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, floating-point, decimal, informix

I am trying to compare values from an Informix database and a SQL Server database. The problem I am getting is that Informix is returning the float as "4000" and SQL Server is returning it as "40.000.000".

The datatype of the Informix column is "float" and the datatype of the SQL Server column is decimal(8,2).

The comparison is happening in a C# application, and it is always failing because of what is returned.

The data coming from the Informix database is being inserted directly into the SQL Server database, so the comparison should be accurate when pulling the values back out.

I'm not sure how to tackle this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: The obvious questions are "what is the value stored in the Informix database"; and "what is the value stored in the SQL Server database".  The SQL Server value is a little unusually formatted; I assume that is 40 million in a locale where the decimal point is a comma and dot is used for a thousands separator.  Do you have access to either database using tools other than C#?  Can you validate the values in the tables using those?  For example, Informix has a crude but effective tool called DB-Access; what does it say when it selects the data from its database?

Comment: I really don't have access to the values inside of the Informix database other than using C#, but on the other hand, in the SQL Server database the value is listed as 40.00. I believe the value inside of the Informix database will would be some form of "40.00", as the field is for "hours available". Edit: When linking to the table in Access, the value in the Informix table is "40".

Comment: If the field in SQL Server has the value 40 but is being shown as '40.000.000', then that's a problem.  Which locale are you using?  Which character is the decimal point, and which character is the thousands separator?  I wonder if there's a danger that the Informix driver is being confused or misled about the locale and is formatting the value as a string `40.00` (with a dot), but this is then converted treating the dot as a thousands separator, yielding 4000 as the value.

Comment: What do you mean in regards to what locale am I using? I'm really not sure how to find that out.

Comment: Which country are you from?  Which set of cultural conventions are used in the code you're working with?  Is the decimal point a comma or a dot?  Is the thousands separator a dot or a comma?  (They're usually complementary pairs...but they could be something else.)

Comment: Oh, I understand what you were getting at now. I'm from the USA, with the comma being the thousands, and the period being the decimal point.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16661/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-b-rizzy)

Comment: I don't think locale or environment variables alter the way numeric values are stored in a database. These variables only apply to how the value is displayed or printed.

Answer (score 1):

Has this problem been resolved?.. It appears as if the Informix DBMONEY environment value could be set to use periods instead of commas for the thousands delimiter, but that still should not affect the value when its sent to SQL Server. Have you tested with other values to see if there's a pattern?

I also recall that with Informix FLOAT and SMALLFLOAT datatypes, sometimes values can become skewed from one computer hardware architecture to another.

Comment: It has been resolved. It was an error on my part, that really had nothing to do with the data types in the first place.